# How to subject the function argument to typeclass instantiation?

Tags: haskell

Okay, I can do this:

```
class Fun fun where
    fm :: (b -> b) -> fun b -> fun b

instance Fun ((->) a) where
    fm g f = g . f
```

Can I also instantiate `Fun` with regard to the argument instead of the result?

Something like this:

```
instance Fun (\x -> (->) x a) where
    fm g f = f . g
```

That is just conceptual because I don't know how to write this correctly - but I hope the idea is made clear.

I also tried this:

```
type F b a = (->) a b

instance Fun (F b) where
    fm g f = f . g
```

But that seems to be fundamentally flawed.

---

In other words: `(->) a b` is a `Fun`. Is `(<-) a b` also a `Fun`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, but only with a newtype:

```
newtype BackFun a b = BackFun (b -> a)

instance Fun (BackFun a) where
  fm g (BackFun f) = BackFun (f . g)
```

The problem is that, even with extensions, you can't use a partially applied type alias in an instance declaration, so:

```
type F b a = (->) a b
instance Fun (F b)
```

won't work because `F b` in the instance declaration hasn't been fully applied.

The only other way to flip the order of the parameters to the `(->)` constructor is to wrap it in a newtype as above.